# How can I trigger or force a CSS transition in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I want my `GtkTextView` to do an animated transition to a different background color when I click a button. Here's what I tried:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget *window, *fixed, *text_view, *button;

static void button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {

    GtkStyleContext *context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(text_view);
    gtk_style_context_add_class(context, "green-background");
}

static void app_activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {

    GtkCssProvider *cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(cssProvider, "sandbox.css", NULL);

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Sandbox");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(window), 400, 250);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(button), 50, 25);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), NULL);

    text_view = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(text_view), 200, 100);

    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button, 10, 10);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), text_view, 100, 100);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);    

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(window), 10, 10);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("the.application.id", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(app_activate), NULL);

    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);

    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}
```

Here's my CSS file (**sandbox.css**):

```
GtkTextView {
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

.green-background {
    background-color: green;
}
```

This changes the background color of the `GtkTextView` immediately when I click the button instead of transitioning.

I'm using GTK version 3.18.9.

Comment: I am guessing the class overrides the transition. You may want to move the transition into the class. See also: [how CSS transitions work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions). Can't check right now though; sorry.

Comment: That didn't work. The link you provided has a `:hover` example that uses a similar pattern to what I tried. [Here's an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/m5cv34ck/3/)

Comment: [Here's something closer](https://jsfiddle.net/kcvtqeuq/1/) to what I tried in GTK that works well in a web page.

Comment: Could be that there was no transition because there was not a `background-color` property already set, but I'm not sure without trying...

Comment: @ptomato I just tried it. It didn't help.